# Are the border checkpoints in Neum (Croatia-Bosnia) joint checkpoints?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, croatia, bosnia

I'm Aware that Croatia operates some joint checkpoints with Slovenia and Bosnia, meaning both countries check you at the same location.

Are the crossings in Neum of this Kind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crossings in Neum, or to be more specific, Klek border crossing and Zaton Doli border crossing, are normal joint border crossings. It means, that both countries have booths on each crossing, however they are not always occupied, so it may be that there will be only border guard from the country you are about to enter (meaning no exit control).

There may be additional person in the booth labelled "Carina", which is for customs official, in which you have to declare your goods, if they are taxable on entering.

Source:
I have travelled more than a dozen times between Croatia, B&H and Croatia via Neum.

Comment: Have you done this trip recently? Croatia built a new border facility on one of these borders a few years ago, didn't they? Did that change anything? Also, "joint" in this case means you still have to stop twice, doesn't it, as the vision officer and the BiH officer occupy different booths? This is in contrast to some crossings between Croatia and Slovenia, as I understand it.

Comment: Interesting. So, if you enter Bosnia and get an entry stamp (if you're not just in transit, but are going to visit Bosnia for a while) and when leaving there's no Bosnian official, how do you get the Bosnian exit stamp? Also @phoog , by joint I mean the checks are at the same location, while "normal" crossings have the countries 100-200 metres separated from each other

Comment: @Crazydre I've been through Neum many times, just not recently, and always during tourist season. I've never been there when I didn't see both Croatian and Bosnian-Herzegovinian officers at both borders.

Comment: @phoog Alright, but did the Croatian and Bosnian checks take place at a single location (even if obviously at different booths), or did you have to drive for a while to reach the next checkpoint (which is the standard worldwide)?

Comment: Had to drive maybe 10 or 20 meters, IIRC, but this was at the old checkpoint, which was, I think, on Bosnian soil. Croatia built a new facility on Croatian soil; I don't know if the Bosnians moved or not.

Comment: @Crazydre if you look at the satellite on Google maps, it looks like both border facilities comprise separate buildings for the authorities of each country, built in the same general area, both on the Croatian side of the border.  The old (much smaller) facilities were quite far from the border, like one or two km.

Comment: @phoog - I have been travelling via Neum 4 times this September. I had to stop in one facility only, and judging from labels on the booths, there were for both B&H and Croatian guards. I have seen them also walking around the complex. Concerning the booths, and howto behave: I generally stop at every occupied booth with my passports in hand and only some of the officers wanted to check or scan them (note that this seems to be common for EU or Polish passports only).

Comment: @Crazydre - what may be an internation standard that there are separate border checks - I have only travelled in Europe, where this thing may be / was not so common. 
I have never been stamped on Bosnian/Croatian border, but again, this can be the case for an EU passport. I believe that in your example, one will receive while exiting Bosnia an entry stamp for the EU (Croatia), especially if one is required to have a visa to enter. I have been stamped on entry to Montenegro and wasn't stamped on exit and didn't have any problem with that.

Comment: @EdmundDantes Bosnia is supposed to stamp any non-Bosnian passport (while Croatia doesn't stamp EU/EFTA passports), but often at smaller crossings they don't unless asked, which can cause Problems on exit in you're iunlucky. Thankfully I just use my ID Card for both, but my travel companion doesn't have one :/

Comment: @Crazydre - I know they should, but I have travelled to Croatia via Neum at least 12 times as well as a few times through Doljani border crossing (near Metkovic and Capljina), Prud crossing and so on... Always on passport, the best I got was having my passport's machine code scanned :)

Comment: @phoog - "it looks like both border facilities comprise separate buildings for the authorities of each country, built in the same general area".

If you refer to this: [link](https://goo.gl/maps/BBxBeijzaym), then the two  largest buildings with blue roof are for opposite directions (check on the satellite how the lanes go).

Comment: @EdmundDantes Yep, just found a YouTube Video. It is a joint crossing, and it's a joke - often you're waved through even by the Bosnians. What an easy way to enter Bosnia illegally

Comment: @Crazydre I've been through numerous road crossings in the former Yugoslavia, and it was also very common treatment at pre-Schengen Slovenian crossings and pre-EU Croatian crossings.  I got the sense, however, that the treatment given to a vehicle's occupants depended somewhat on the country of the vehicle's registration.

Comment: @phoog With what country plates being given favourable treatment?

Comment: @Crazydre in every case the car I traveled in was registered in either the country I was leaving or the one I was entering.